# How does SharePoint determine WebPart Location for Classic Site page?

Tags: web-part, sitepages, classic-experience

I am trying to write a program which migrates classic sharepoint site pages to a different site/tenant.

I am using this code to import:

```
var deslimitedWebPartManager = destFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
var desWebPartDefinition = deslimitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart(updatedXml);
var newWebPartDefinition = deslimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(desWebPartDefinition.WebPart, webPart.zoneId, webPart.Index);
```

The issue I am having is that the zoneId is "wpz". From:

https://piyushksingh.com/2014/04/10/add-a-new-webpart-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-client-object-model-c/

I am aware that the "wpz" zone means I need to [wikifield] field on the item.

This page (and others) say that I should be place it by adding HTML similar to

```
<snippit only> id="vid_{0}" </snippit only>
```

where {0} is the id of the webpart.

This is fine, however I am trying to determine the location from the source page, and on my source site, the id that is showing on the HTML is NOT the ID of the existing webpart, so I have no way of determine the original location on the source site.

The actual HTML on my source site is:

```
<div unselectable="on" class="ms-rtestate-notify ms-rtestate-read
                  f375072f-60dd-4ead-a999-f92b5416c564" id="div_f375072f-60dd-4ead-a999-f92b5416c564"></div> <div unselectable="on" class="ms-rtestate-read" id="vid_f375072f-60dd-4ead-a999-f92b5416c564" style="display:none;"></div>
```

So you would assume that *f375072f-60dd-4ead-a999-f92b5416c564* is the ID of the webpart, but it is actually *65b8f64e-392b-40c0-8b77-6eeccca713e3*

So I'm wondering where sharepoint stores that this should be the location of this webpart